# How do I fix a hyperlink to a subpage's label? Bootsrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm working on my first big project. I've built almost everything but the menu has problems. Clicking on the link in the menu opens the subpage but does not go to the label.

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="dropdown_target" href="#">
    <span class="caret"></span>
Nurty</a>
<div class="dropdown-menu aria-labelledby=dropdown_target">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/nurty.html">Techouse</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/nurty.html#minit">Minimal</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/nurty.html#classt">Classic</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/nurty.html#detrt">Detroit</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item disabled" href="/nurty.html#hardgroove">Hardgroove</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/nurty.html#hart">Hard</a>
</div>
```

In subpage I want to go for example to this label:

```
<section id="minit">
```

But still not working.

How can I fix it or maybe is other way to do it?

Comment: add only #minit not `/nurty.html#minit` ok!

Comment: The same problem. Opens the nurty.html page but does not transfer to the #minit label.

Answer (score 1):

this is the working example of your need, i also added smooth scoll by  adding css `smooth-behavior: smooth`, i added `1500px` height for clear view of your problem

**Index.html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="dropdown_target" href="#">
        <span class="caret"></span>
        Nurty
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu aria-labelledby=dropdown_target">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="example.html">Techouse</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="example.html#minit">Minimal</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="example.html#classt">Classic</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="example.html#detrt">Detroit</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item disabled" href="example.html#hardgroove">Hardgroove</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="example.html#hart">Hard</a>
    </div>
</li>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**example.html**

```
<style>
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
</style>

<div style="height: 1500px;"></div> <!-- FOR SCROLL VIEW -->
<section id="minit">scroll or die</section>
```

Comment: On nurty.html is no problem with going to label. Problem is from other pages.

Comment: i don't understand, what are you talking about. can you give me pen or fiddle of your problem ?

Comment: Label #minit is inside nurty.html. I want display it from index.html

Comment: so when you click from index.html, you need to go in nurty.html and scroll to #minit ?

Comment: you are doing some mistake bro

Comment: go to my [site](https://nisharg.me/stackoverflow.html) and click on `nurty->minimal` and see what happened